# how to calculate Saturday and Sunday in 2 random dates using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I Want to show Output for how many Saturday And Sunday comes between two Random Dates. I already calculate Saturday and Sunday in one month. but no idea about 2 random dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find below code for you question.

```
$start = new DateTime('2017-02-01');
$end = new DateTime('2017-02-20');
$days = $start->diff($end, true)->days;
$saturdays = intval($days / 6) + ($start->format('N') + $days % 6 >= 6);
$sundays = intval($days / 7) + ($start->format('N') + $days % 7 >= 7);

echo $sundays;
echo $saturdays;
```

Thanks 
Hope! This will help you

Comment: But Sir, in case I am giving input from a client, then how to calculate Saturday and Sunday. 2 date field include in my form first field is s_date  and second one is e_date the field type is date only.

Comment: Take start and end date from form and store in variable, then pass it in DateTime function.

Comment: But take care with format of date